# Using Firebase's REST Auth API for password change

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, rest

I've been using [Firebase's REST Auth API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) and everything's been great so far.

I'm trying to implement a password change feature (not reset, *change*), and I want to ask the user for the current password, validate it, then allow them to set their new password. Reading over the documentation, I see two approaches I can take:

1. Use the password to re-login and check for a 200 return code. The issue with this is that the previous `idToken` will expire and I'll have to reset my Redux state—which isn't too bad.
2. I know I can obtain the [user's password hash](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-get-account-info) , and if there's a way I can obtain Firebase's hashing algorithm, apply it, and compare to the database's password hash, I can also verify the password. This method just seems like a lot of work.

Is there a more straightforward approach, or am I best off sticking with option 1?

Comment: Why do you need to verify the current password? Isn't your user logged in ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Isn't it standard to ask the user to verify their current password? If a user leaves their phone on the table, they may get their password changed without them knowing.

Comment: You are right . I didn't consider 'user leaves their phone' case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

Asking user to enter their password sounds good but that's redundant and the API call of resetting password does not depend on that. So anyone can just make a direct API request to change the password.

**Approach 2:**

This kind of sounds overkill to me. Also you'll have to deal with complex flow with [scrypt](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/scrypt/) and chances of someone bypassing it still exists.

I would go with approach one but to prevent someone from bypassing it, I'll perform the password reset part in a Cloud function. Because you are getting a new token which is just generated after user has entered the password, you can compare the timestamp of token creation ([`auth_time`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.DecodedIdToken#auth_time) property) in the Cloud function. If it is older than N minutes, ask the user to enter password again.

The `auth_time` property of decoded id token is the time, in seconds since the Unix epoch, when the end-user authentication occurred. You could also use `iat` which is the time at which this ID token was issued but that token could be of the older session (when user had not entered the password).

You can then update user's password using Firebase Admin SDK's [updateUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) method.

*Do note that this does not prevent anyone who gets the ID Token from a device where a user is already logged in from changing the password using REST API directly. This is just a workaround to get the desired password change flow. It's up to the user to prevent any malicious user from getting physical access to their device.*

Comment: Hey Dharmaraj :). So with the first approach, the current password isn't a part of the reset password API, but the user's `idToken` is, which can only be obtained by logging into the account. So anyone *not on the current authenticated device* will not have access to the `idToken` without having the user's login credentials. Anyone who tried to change the password *on the authenticated device* (and thus have the `idToken` as part of state) will need to type in the current password. Does this sound safe to you?

Comment: @SamLiu this is purely a workaround to get desired auth flow... if anyone gets the id token from a device where use is already logged in, they can still change the password using the REST API. But if you want to prevent changing passwords directly from your web app you can make route that process through a cloud function as mentioned in answer.

Comment: What do you mean by cloud function. I was thinking of using another one of Firebase's API <a href="https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-change-password">endpoints</a> to make the password change.

Comment: @SamLiu my intention to say that was, the API you are referring to can be used just with existing ID token that user has and does not require you to ask password to the user before hand. (but so do using Cloud function is). The auth flow you are trying to create whether it be approach 1 or 2 is redundant and just for sake of asking user.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying now—anyone with an `idToken` can bypass the current password request in the app and just directly make the API call with that `idToken`. One more question: is it even possible for someone to get the `idToken`? It's in the Redux state of my application; is there a way for someone to extract that value in a production app?

Comment: @SamLiu Users can of course see their own ID token however unless any malicious script is injected in your app or someone gets physical access to user's device, no one can get any other user's ID Token. There's nothing much you can do there, users must keep their devices safe.

Comment: Another thing. If you take a look at this list: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth. There are many harmful API calls that a hacker can perform with just the `idToken` (e.g. delete account, change email, change password). Would I have to secure each of these endpoints? Based on the way the API is set up, it seems like the `idToken` alone is sufficient authentication

Comment: @SamLiu I won't say them harmful. ID token is granted aft successful authentication only. Tokens refresh every hour so bruteforcing them is extremely difficult only. So far from my experience only way to get someone else ID token would be phishing like asking some user who has no user knowledge with tech to type something in browser console or getting physical access to their device...